# GridLayout with images going off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create a `GridLayout` with images. The grid has 3 columns.

I have a few problems though:

1. The `ImageView`s are going off the screen, as shown in the image below. The `GridLayout` isn't properly setting the width of the `ImageView`s to fit.

[image]

2. There is no space/margin between the `ImageView`s, even though I have set the `horizontalSpacing` and `verticalSpacing` properties for the `GridLayout`.

Here is my current code. What should I change to fix my two problems?

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

</GridLayout>
```

---

### Update

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144381/8055139), I tried using the following layout:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <com.my.package.view.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <com.my.package.view.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

    <com.my.package.view.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Color_DarkRed" />

</GridLayout>
```

But it comes out looking like the image below. Each `ImageView` takes up the entire width of the screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k5YN.png

Comment: If you can use linear layout instead of grid layout, you can then use 'weight attribute' to linearly fit your ellements.

Comment: Your screen isn't guaranteed to be 390dp (or 410 with the spacing) wide...

Comment: @cricket_007 Even if I change it to `20dp`, it still doesn't stretch the images to create 3 columns that fill the width of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the layout_width="130dp" because your screen isn't guaranteed to be 390dp

Comment: Okay, but even if I change it to `20dp`, it doesn't stretch to fit the width of the `GridLayout` to make 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Change the images or you can also use Square Image View for proper sizing of your Grid Items.

Create a separate class for defining the size dynamically for your ImageView that should inherit ImageView class as shown below:

```
    public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);

    }
}
```

The setMeasuredDimension(width, width); will automatically set your height as the width.

In xml file use this class as a view in place of ImageView as shown below:

```
<com.packagepath.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/Imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Just tried this. Still running into issues. I updated the bottom of my question so you can see what's the problem still.

Comment: change the match_parent with fill_parent